# Why does it show I have no disk space left while I still have a lot of space available?

Tags: centos, diskspace

I am on a CentOs system, and df shows that I have a lot of disk spaces available:

See this command:

```
$ git pull
fatal: write error: No space left on device

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        30G  4.2G   24G  15% /
devtmpfs         63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            63G  435M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2        30G   28G     0 100% /usr
/dev/sda7       148G   24G  118G  17% /data0
/dev/sda6        30G  1.3G   27G   5% /var
/dev/sda5        30G   45M   28G   1% /tmp
/dev/sdc1       3.9T  462G  3.3T  13% /data1
/dev/sdb1       274G  107G  154G  42% /data2
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/60422
```

And I am currently running the git pull command under /data1, which has 87% spaces left.

Why is that?

EDIT:

```
df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        1.9M   14K  1.9M    1% /
devtmpfs          16M   610   16M    1% /dev
tmpfs             16M     1   16M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             16M  1022   16M    1% /run
tmpfs             16M    16   16M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2        1.9M  344K  1.6M   18% /usr
/dev/sda7        9.5M   58K  9.4M    1% /data0
/dev/sda6        1.9M   14K  1.9M    1% /var
/dev/sda5        1.9M    35  1.9M    1% /tmp
/dev/sdc1        251M  160K  251M    1% /data1
/dev/sdb1         18M  1.2K   18M    1% /data2
tmpfs             16M     1   16M    1% /run/user/60422
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running out of inodes? Check with `df -ih`.

Comment: What's inodes? I added the output and please see. Also, /dev/sda2        30G   28G     0 100% /usr. Is this the cause? But I am working under /data1

Comment: Your inodes look ok... Can you clear something from /usr and see if that helps?